# Grouping operations on two levels with for each level an element - array association

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-mongodb

I am working on JHipster project with an AngularJS front-end and a java back-end. I am using Spring Data with the MongoDB database.

I did a grouping operation on a String field called `budgetCode`. So, for each `budgetCode`, there is a list of the linked `taskCodes` which is another String field. I succeeded to do that by another Stackoverflow post: "*Grouping operation on a field and putting the list of the liked field in an array*"

Here, the method aggregateAllTaskCode which does the grouping operation:

**Repository layer**

```
public class ClarityResourceAffectationRepositoryImpl implements ClarityResourceAffectationRepositoryCustom {
    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Override
    public List<ClarityResourceAffectationReport> aggregateAllTaskCode() {

        AggregationOperation project = new AggregationOperation() {
            @Override
            public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
                return new BasicDBObject("$project", new BasicDBObject("budget_code", "$budget_code").append("task_code", Arrays.asList("$task_code")));
            }
        };

        Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(project,
                group("budgetCode").addToSet("budgetCode").as("budgetCode").addToSet("taskCode").as("taskCode"),
                sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, previousOperation(),"budgetCode"));

        AggregationResults groupResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, ClarityResourceAffectation.class,
                ClarityResourceAffectationReport.class);
        List<ClarityResourceAffectationReport> clarityResourceAffectationReports = groupResults.getMappedResults();

        return clarityResourceAffectationReports;
    }
}
```

**Service layer**

```
public class ClarityResourceAffectationServiceImpl implements ClarityResourceAffectationService{
    @Override
    public List<ClarityResourceAffectationReport> aggregateAllTaskCodes() {
        log.debug("Request to aggregateAllTaskCodes: {}");
        List<ClarityResourceAffectationReport> result = clarityResourceAffectationRepository
                .aggregateAllTaskCodes();

        return result;
    }
}
```

**REST API layer**

```
public class ClarityResourceAffectationResource {
    @GetMapping("/clarity-resource-affectations/list-task-codes")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<List<ClarityResourceAffectationReport>> aggregateTabAllTaskCodes() {
        log.debug("REST request to get aggregateTabAllTaskCodes : {}");
        List<ClarityResourceAffectationReport> result = clarityResourceAffectationService.aggregateAllTaskCodes();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Here, the ClarityResourceAffectation and the ClarityResourceAffectationReport files:

**ClarityResourceAffectation**

```
@Document(collection = "clarity_resource_affectation")
public class ClarityResourceAffectation implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field("budget_code")
    private String budgetCode;

    @Field("task_code")
    private String taskCode;

    @Field("action_code")
    private String actionCode;

    public String getBudgetCode() {
        return budgetCode;
    }

    public void setBudgetCode(String budgetCode) {
        this.budgetCode = budgetCode;
    }

    public String getTaskCode() {
        return taskCode;
    }

    public void setTaskCode(String taskCode) {
        this.taskCode = taskCode;
    }

    public String getActionCode() {
        return actionCode;
    }

    public void setActionCode(String actionCode) {
        this.actionCode = actionCode;
    }
}
```

**ClarityResourceAffectationReport**

```
public class ClarityResourceAffectationReport implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String[] budgetCodes;
    private String[][] taskCodes;
    private String[][][] actionCodes;

    public String[] getBudgetCodes() {
        return budgetCodes;
    }

    public void setBudgetCodes(String[] budgetCodes) {
        this.budgetCodes = budgetCodes;
    }

    public String[][] getTaskCodes() {
        return taskCodes;
    }

    public void setTaskCodes(String[][] taskCodes) {
        this.taskCodes = taskCodes;
    }

    public String[][][] getActionCodes() {
        return actionCodes;
    }

    public void setActionCodes(String[][][] actionCodes) {
        this.actionCodes = actionCodes;
    }
}
```

**A sample example of what I have in the database**

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_class": "fr.bpce.kpi.clarity.domain.ClarityResourceAffectation",
    "budget_code": "P24DCDSA01",
    "task_code": "61427",
    "action_code": "354"
}
/* 1 */
{
    "_class": "fr.bpce.kpi.clarity.domain.ClarityResourceAffectation",
    "budget_code": "P24DCDSA01",
    "task_code": "61427",
    "action_code": "121"
}
/* 2 */
{
    "_class": "fr.bpce.kpi.clarity.domain.ClarityResourceAffectation",
    "budget_code": "P24DCDSA01",
    "task_code": "65434",
    "action_code": "143"
}
/* 3 */
{
    "_class": "fr.bpce.kpi.clarity.domain.ClarityResourceAffectation",
    "budget_code": "P24DCDSA01",
    "task_code": "65434",
    "action_code": "463"
}
/* 4 */
{
    "_class": "fr.bpce.kpi.clarity.domain.ClarityResourceAffectation",
    "budget_code": "P24PR00",
    "task_code": "60298",
    "action_code": "255"
}
/* 5 */
{
    "_class": "fr.bpce.kpi.clarity.domain.ClarityResourceAffectation",
    "budget_code": "P24PR00",
    "task_code": "60298",
    "action_code": "127"
}
/* 6 */
{
    "_class": "fr.bpce.kpi.clarity.domain.ClarityResourceAffectation",
    "budget_code": "P24PR00",
    "task_code": "67875",
    "action_code": "348"
}
/* 7 */
{
    "_class": "fr.bpce.kpi.clarity.domain.ClarityResourceAffectation",
    "budget_code": "P24PR00",
    "task_code": "67875",
    "action_code": "654"
}
```

For the moment, I have for a budgetCode `["P221P00"]`, a list of linked taskCodes `[["2630"],["61297"],["61296"],["61299"]]`. I would like to add a third field in the **ClarityResourceAffectationReport** file `String[][][]actionCode` in order to have another level of grouping. By this way each element of the `taskCodes` list will be linked to a list of `actionCode`. In the other Stackoverflow post, Veeram advised me to do two groups, one group on `budgetCode` and `taskCodes` and push `actionCode` and another group on `budgetCode` and push both `taskCodes` and `actionCode` from previous group.

So, I developped a method with two project operations and two aggregation operations. I am not sure if it is like that. Also, I don't know how to form the group results because now, we have two aggregation operations. Also, I consider that now in the ClarityResourceAffectationReport, I have three arrays: `String[] budgetCodes, String[][] taskCodes, String[][][] actionCodes`.

```
@Override
public List<ClarityResourceAffectationReport> aggregateAllBudgetCode() {

        //I did two projects instantiations
        AggregationOperation projectBudgetTask = new AggregationOperation() {
            @Override
            public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
                return new BasicDBObject("$project", new BasicDBObject("budget_code", "$budget_code").append("task_code", Arrays.asList("$task_code")));
            }
        };

        AggregationOperation projectTaskAction = new AggregationOperation() {
            @Override
            public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
                return new BasicDBObject("$project", new BasicDBObject("task_code", "$task_code").append("action_code", Arrays.asList("$action_code")));
            }
        };

        //I did two aggregation methods
        Aggregation aggregationBudgetTask = newAggregation(projectBudgetTask,
                group("budgetCode", "taskCode").addToSet("budgetCodeTaskCode").as("budgetCodeTaskCode").addToSet("actionCode").as("actionCode"),
                sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, previousOperation(),"budgetCode", "taskCode"));

        Aggregation aggregationTaskAction = newAggregation(projectTaskAction,
                group("budgetCode").addToSet("budgetCode").as("budgetCode").addToSet("taskCodes").as("taskCodes").addToSet("actionCode").as("actionCode"),
                sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, previousOperation(),"budgetCode"));        

        //Here, how can I put the two aggregation methods?
        AggregationResults groupResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, clarityResourceAffectation.class,
                ClarityResourceAffectationReport.class);
        List<ClarityResourceAffectationReport> clarityResourceAffectationReport = groupResults.getMappedResults();

        return clarityResourceAffectationReport ;
    }
```

In the first aggregation operation, I did a `group("budgetCode", "taskCode")` and after that I put an `addToSet("budgetCodeTaskCode").as("budgetCodeTaskCode")` because I would like to take into account a group operation. But, actually what I would like to do is `group("budgetCode", "taskCode").addToSet("budgetCode", "taskCode").as("budgetCode", "taskCode")`. But, in an `addToSet` and an `as` methods, we cannot put two arguments. So, how do we have to do? And also, how can I put the two aggregation methods in a `AggregationResults groupResults`?

**I tried that but it did not function**

In order to differentiate `clarityResourceAffectation` and `clarityResourceAffectationReport` I added a "s" letter at each fields of the report class. I updated the post.

Here, the code I tried with one aggregation operation:

```
@Override
public List<ClarityResourceAffectationReport> aggregateAllTaskCode() {

    AggregationOperation project = new AggregationOperation() {
         @Override
         public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
           return new BasicDBObject("$project", new BasicDBObject("task_code", "$task_code").append("action_code", Arrays.asList("$action_code")));
        }
    };

    Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(project,
              group("budgetCode", "taskCode").addToSet("actionCode").as("actionCodes"),
              group("budgetCode").first("taskCode").as("taskCode").addToSet(new BasicDBObject("taskCode","$_id.taskCode").append("actionCodes", "$actionCodes")).as("taskCodes"),
              sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, previousOperation(),"taskCodes"));

    AggregationResults groupResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, ClarityResourceAffectation.class,
            ClarityResourceAffectationReport.class);
    List<ClarityResourceAffectationReport> clarityResourceAffectationReports = groupResults.getMappedResults();

    log.debug("clarityResourceAffectationReports.size()" + clarityResourceAffectationReports.size());
    log.debug("aggregation.toString()" + aggregation.toString());

    return clarityResourceAffectationReports;
}
```

I did not function and I have an error which is: `f.b.k.l.w.r.errors.ExceptionTranslator   : Target bean of type [[Ljava.lang.String; is not of type of the persistent entity ([Ljava.lang.String;)!`. Anyway, in the code you put also `.append("actionCodes", "actionCodes")).as("taskCodeActionCodes")` after the second group. Can you explain what is `taskCodeActionCodes`?

**The result with flat structure**

I changed a little the types of the `ResourceAffectationReport` fields: String budgetCodes, String[] taskCodes et String[][] actionCodes.

```
[
  {
    "budgetCodes": "P24D001",
    "taskCodes": [
      "64578"
    ],
    "actionCodes": [
      [
        "454"
      ],
      [
        "253"
      ],
      [
        "745"
      ],
      [
        "354"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "budgetCodes": "P24D002",
    "taskCodes": [
      "62678"
    ],
    "actionCodes": [
      [
        "857"
      ],
      [
        "907"
      ],
      [
        "858"
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

**The result with map structure**

Here, the types of the report file String budgetCode, String[] taskCodes, String[][] actionCodes, List> taskCodesActionCodes.

```
[
  {
    "budgetCodes": "P24D001",
    "taskCodes": null,
    "actionCodes": null,
    "taskCodesactionCodes": [
      {
        "[Ljava.lang.String;@7e695137": [
          [
            "64578"
          ]
        ],
        "[Ljava.lang.String;@48ec311a": [
          [
            "454"
          ],
          [
            "253"
          ],
          [
            "745"
          ],
          [
            "354"
          ]
        ]
      },
      {
        "[Ljava.lang.String;@258b30b6": [
          [
            "62678"
          ]
        ],
        "[Ljava.lang.String;@481154c7": [
          [
            "857"
          ],
          [
            "907"
          ],
          [
            "858"
          ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "budgetCodes": "P24D002",
    "taskCodes": null,
    "actionCodes": null,
    "taskCodesActionCodes": [
      {
        "[Ljava.lang.String;@1cdf4a9e": [
          [
            "64568"
          ]
        ],
        "[Ljava.lang.String;@1613fdbb": [
          [
            "764"
          ],
          [
            "984"
          ],
          [
            "489"
          ]
        ]
      },
      {
        "[Ljava.lang.String;@53167f62": [
          [
            "63887"
          ]
        ],
        "[Ljava.lang.String;@5a30c8de": [
          [
            "757"
          ],
          [
            "394"
          ],
          [
            "294"
          ],
          [
            "765"
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The map structure method is interesting but I have some problems in order to display that in my front-end but it is another problems because of the key which was of object type. I will test again and I will tell you. Anyway, it is interresting. Actually, I had another idea. What I want is that in each JSON document I have one String field budgetCodes, one String[] field taskCodes which will contain all 
taskCodes linked to the budgetCodes and I think finally what is really adapted to what I want is to create a TaskCode class like that:

```
public class TaskCode {
    private String taskCode;
    private String[] actionCode;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

By this way, it will allow me to have for each JSON document, a simple String with a budgetCode, a list of the linked TaskCodes with for 
each taskCode object, the String attribute taskCode which will contain the taskCode's value. And finally each taskCode object will contain a String[] 
with the list of actionCodes.

**Concerning the POJO structure**

It functions well but I have some problems in order to display the data in the AngularJS front-end. I wanted to do an aggregation operation in order to create a menu in which each click on an element will open a sub-menu with a sub-list and so on and so forth... I don't know if an aggregation is really adapted to what I want to do. So, I thought about another method. Instead of doing an aggregation operation, perhaps an other method can be to retrieve the data I wanted with simple find operations from the database and use the service layer in order do a tree algorith.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This would probably be a lot clearer if you showed some sample documents and the output you are expecting to get from them. The danger with the way this question is currently structured is that your "attempts" may well be completely missing the mark of the result you need to get to. That's why it is often best to *"ask by example"* so there is a clear "source" and "result" to get to. Also please do not "tag" your question with every component in your project. You are asking about "spring-mongo" and the "aggregation-framework" **only** in terms of applied tags to the actual question.

Comment: I understand what you told. Actually, I just want to group on 2 levels knowing that each result must be put in an sub array. That is why for the `ClarityResourceAffection` (for the input fields), there are three String fields `String budgetCode, String taskCode, String actionCode` and for the `ClarityResourceAffectionReport` (for the output fields), there are three arrays `String[] budgetCode, String[][] taskCode, String[][][] actionCode`. By this way, `String[] budgetCode` will contain all the budgetCodes, and `String[][] taskCode` will contain a list of taskCodes for each budgetCode etc...

Comment: You do realize we cannot see your computer screen from here. So I'm asking you to show some data and a desired result. Your code does not explain this very well. Edit your question to include the documents please.

Comment: I added what I have in the database with some identical values in other to make it easier to understand the different groupings I need.

Comment: You probably should also add what your expected output is just like was also asked. When adding expected output it should reflect what can be obtained from the sample documents given See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What I keep telling you is your code is not an accurate indication of what you want which is *"How do I get this result?"*. So if you show the "result" and you show the documents to use to comprise the result, then it's a clear question with a clear answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform multiple level groupings in a single aggregation pipeline.

Updated existing project stage to include `actionCode` and updated existing group to include `actionCode`.

This will display the flatten structure with each row containing `budgetCodes`, `taskCodes` and  `actionCodes`.

Update your `actionCodes` to `private String[][] actionCodes;`

**Flat Structure.**

Something like

```
 AggregationOperation project = new AggregationOperation() {
   @Override
    public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
         return new BasicDBObject("$project", new BasicDBObject("budget_code", 1).append("task_code",  Arrays.asList("$task_code")).append("action_code", Arrays.asList("$action_code")));
       }
    };

Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(project,
         group("budgetCode", "taskCode").addToSet("actionCode").as("actionCodes"),
         project("actionCodes").and("_id.budgetCode").as("budgetCodes").and("_id.taskCode").as("taskCodes").andExclude("_id"),
         sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "budgetCodes","taskCodes"));
```

**Map like Structure.**

Adjust your output DTO to

```
private String[] budgetCodes;
private List<Map<String[], String[][]>> taskCodeActionCodes;
```

This will output result into Map to give you multiple groupings.

Something like

```
AggregationOperation project = new AggregationOperation() {
  @Override
  public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
       return new BasicDBObject("$project", new BasicDBObject("budget_code", 1).append("task_code",  Arrays.asList("$task_code")).append("action_code", Arrays.asList("$action_code")));
     }
  };

Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(project,
         group("budgetCode", "taskCode").addToSet("actionCode").as("actionCodes"),
         group("_id.budgetCode").addToSet(new BasicDBObject("taskCode","$_id.taskCode").append("actionCodes", "$actionCodes")).as("taskCodeActionCodes"),
            project("taskCodeActionCodes").and("budgetCodes").previousOperation().andExclude("_id"),
         sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "budgetCodes"));
```

**POJO Structure**

```
public class ClarityResourceAffectationReport {

    private String budgetCode;
    private List<TaskCode> linkedTaskCodes;
}


public class TaskCode {
    private String taskCode;
    private String[] actionCode;

}

Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
          group("budgetCode", "taskCode").addToSet("actionCode").as("actionCode"),
          group("_id.budgetCode").addToSet(new BasicDBObject("taskCode","$_id.taskCode").append("actionCode", "$actionCode")).as("linkedTaskCodes"),
               project("linkedTaskCodes").and("budgetCode").previousOperation().andExclude("_id"),
         sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "budgetCode"));
```

Comment: I updated the post. I put what I tried but I don't understand some things, for exemple the `taskCodeActionCodes` variable you used in the second group operation. Also, I don't know why you did not put as you did in the `AggregationOperation project`, `task_code` and `action_code` in the `new BasicDBObject` of the aggretation operation. Instead you put `taskCode, $_id.taskCode` and `actionCodes, actionCodes`.

Comment: Sorry, I may have missed somethings here. I've updated answer based on feedback. It looks like you need a flatten results and you don`t need the second group.  The results will be grouped on budget code and task code and corresponding action codes. You've to use a map like data structure to map the relationship between task code and action code if you need second group.

Comment: Thank you for your update. Are you sure that you can use `project` like as you did in the second call in the aggregation method? Because, in my Eclipse, the `project` keyword of `project("actionCodes").and("_id.budgetCode")...` is underlined in red like we cannot use `project` like that.

Comment: Np. It needs a static import. Try `Aggregation.project` instead.

Comment: I've added map solution to capture the association between multiple groups. The `taskCodeActionCodes` map will hold the `actionCodes` for each `taskCodes` from second group while keeping the `budgetCode` that goes with it. This part `addToSet(new BasicDBObject("taskCode","$_id.taskCode").append("actionCodes", "$actionCodes"))` to access previous group values. You need to reference the field (`$ notation` ) as you do in shell for  mongo type `BasicDBObject`.

Comment: Thank you for the two methods! I tested the two methods and there are interresting. Anyway, for what I want I thaught about another methods that I described in the post which I updated.

Comment: You are welcome. I have added a alternative solution as noted by you in the post which is precisely what I wanted to do in the first place but I wasn't sure because as I thought you wanted a array like association structure.

Comment: Thanks! I tested the POJO structure. It functions but I just have some problems to display that in the front-end. Anyway, this aggregation method is good. But, I thought about another solution. So, I updated the post in order to talk about that.

Comment: You are welcome. It doesn't seem like a programming question but more of a design question. Please consider asking another question and someone else can help you. Appreciate your understanding.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to reply. Yes, I will do that.